# Error when compiling a WinForms project that uses SubSonic library

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, subsonic3

The code generation is working but I get the following errors when I try to build the project:

Error 4 Source file '...Project Path...\Structs.cs' could not be opened ('Unspecified error ') PPSGenerator
Error 5 Source file '...Project Path...\Context.cs' could not be opened ('Unspecified error ') PPSGenerator
Error 6 Source file '...Project Path...\ActiveRecord.cs' could not be opened ('Unspecified error ') PPSGenerator
Error 7 Source file '...Project Path...\StoredProcedures.cs' could not be opened ('Unspecified error ') PPSGenerator

I'm using VS2010 on a Windows 7 64 bit machine.  Project is targeting Framework 3.5...  any ideas?

Also noticed the following warnings, but not sure that these are as important:

Warning 1 The C# 2.0 and C# 3.5 compilers are no longer supported. Templates will always be compiled with the version 4 compiler instead of 'v3.5' as specified. ...ProjectPath...\Structs.tt 1 4

Warning 2 Multiple template directives were found in the template. All but the first one will be ignored. Multiple parameters to the template directive should be specified within one template directive. ...ProjectPath...\Settings.ttinclude 1 4

Warning 3 Compiling transformation: The variable 'parameters' is assigned but its value is never used ...ProjectPath...\SQLServer.ttinclude 92 15

Thanks!
Mike D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BEGIN red faced answer to my own question

Ok, I originally dragged the files into my project root, then went out to the file system and deleted those files and dragged the files into my project in the Model folder.  for some reason the project was still looking for the files that were in my project root.  Because I deleted them on the file system I assume that Studio didn't get the memo and was still trying to compile them.

So happy that my first post on StackOverflow was a complete fustercluck.

END red faced answer to my own question